# Mixing React Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to development. Right now working on an webapp in my freetime.
Backend will be written in Python (here I have the best experience).

How good is the Idea to mixing React components: 
like: https://github.com/brillout/awesome-react-components

My Idea was to use these components or let others create components for me (for example a slide show or whatever)

The question is, is this a good Idea? I'm worry that this might create a lot of overhead. For example one component is based on bootstrap and the other on foundation (As I said I'm not experienced web developer and can't judge if this can actualy really happen).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of React components is to have the smallest piece of code you can define.

However, mixing different CSS frameworks, like Bootstrap or Foundation doesn't sound like the best idea. You can, of course mix ready-made components (like React-Bootstrap) with your own custom components, but ideally you would choose one framework and stick with it.

The good thing about React is that you can possibly switch between Frameworks without the need of refactoring everything.

Let's say, for instance, you have a custom component called Slider. If you later decide to use MaterialUI, depending on your configurations, you could just change the import from `import Slider from "./Slider"` to `import Slider from "material-ui/Slider"` and the rest of your code would be untouched.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense. Do you have a suggestion, which UI/CSS Freamework to use in combination with react?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a CSS / UI framework and stick with it. These days I have been working with Semantic UI and they have good integration with React via http://react.semantic-ui.com/

It is awesome! :)

And in addition to that, you can also build your own custom components.

If you think adding a whole framework to your project is a lot of burden, then you can make everything your own from scratch. (Either (1) using the CSS framework classes for the components or (2) defining your own CSS classes)

And to conclude I also agree to not mix CSS frameworks as there might be conflicts! It's not fun! In my project, Bootstrap was conflicting with Semantic UI, so I just stuck with the latter.